# asp.net File.OpenText can't read uploaded file

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, windows-server-2008, file-permissions

I have an ASP.NET MVC application on Windows Server 2008.

I need to upload a file, save it to an archive folder under the App_Data folder, then open and read from it. I can do this on my local machine but can't on the test server. I suspect it is a permissions issue but the permissions appear to be in place.  The relevant C# code:

```
HttpPostedFileBase hpf = Request.Files[0];
var fileLength = hpf.ContentLength;
if (fileLength != 0)
{
    var archiveFolder = Server.MapPath("~/" + folder);
    var archiveFile = "import_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmm") + ".txt";
    var archivePath = Path.Combine(archiveFolder, archiveFile);
    hpf.SaveAs(archivePath);
}
```

The above code saves the file fine.

```
StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(archivePath);
```

The above line throws an error:

> Could not find file 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\usb01312012.txt'.

So although "archivePath" is a path to a saved file under App_Data, ASP.NET looks to the SYSTEM folder for the file.

I have given every permission except Full Control to IIS_USRS on the entire website. Why can't I access the file?

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint at File.OpenText and verify that at that time archivePath indeed hold the requested path?

Comment: I don't think your save code is the problem here. Show a little more of your read code. At a guess, it looks like maybe you have another Server.MapPath for your read codes and it's failing so that you end up with only the file name in archivePath when you do the OpenText.

Comment: "archivePath" is the string that holds the path that is used to both save and read the file. It is the full path "C:\..."

Comment: The archivePath in your code snippet is locally scoped to the if block. If your OpentText is outside of it, you're going to have problems. I've also just noticed that the filename in your error does not match the format that your archiveFile line should produce. Do you have overlapping scopes on something?

Comment: I haven't shown some of the code that is not pertinent. But while debugging on my local machine I can see that the file paths are identical for the SaveAs and the OpenText.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your site runs correct version of asp.net (2.0 or 4.0).

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED: As of the next day, this now works!  I guess IIS had to recycle? Thanks for your comments!